# Failing to call a constructor method on objects stored in the localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures, local-storage, instance

So I'm working on an application that takes in data from users & store it as objects in an array, I then created functionality to store that data in the localStorage. Here is the basic demo of what I'm trying to do:

```
// constructor function

function Book(title, author, pages, read = false) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
  this.status = function() {
    console.log(this.read);
  }
}

// array to store objects

let mybooks = [];

// instances of the Book object

let book1 = new Book('Hello', 'John', 123, true);
let book2 = new Book('Hey', 'Jane', 13, false);
let book3 = new Book('Hi', 'Mary', 12, true);
let book4 = new Book('Holo', 'Peter', 10, false);
let book5 = new Book('Banda', 'Banda', 03, true);

// push the instances to the mybooks array

mybooks.push(book1);
mybooks.push(book2);
mybooks.push(book3);
mybooks.push(book4);
mybooks.push(book5);

// store mybooks to the localStorage

localStorage.mybooks = JSON.stringify(mybooks);

// retrieve data from the localStorage

let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mybooks'));

// call the status() method on each object

data.forEach(book => {
  book.status();
});
```

By calling the .status() method on each object, I expect to get the boolean ( true/false ) value on the console. But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: book.status is not a function
    at app.js:36
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at app.js:35
```

But if I run the same function on each object before storing it on the localStorage, I get the correct output.

Comment: localStorage stores text, not objects. Store the data in json and recreate your objects with the stored data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description) ... any information about an object / instance which can not be transformed into a JSON conform key-value pair will be lost.

Thus, a `Book` instance will be presented by a string as simple as e.g. this ...

```
'{"title":"Hello","author":"John","pages":123,"read":true}'
```

... and in case of parsing such a string via [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) one gets returned an object like ...

```
{ title: "Hello", author: "John", pages: 123, read: true }
```

... which still might be capable of representing a book through the data it carries, but it can not be used anymore like a real `Book` instance that e.g. features an inherited `status` method that at any time could be used for such an instance.

In order to solve the problem the OP has to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the parsed array of raw book data items (the one from the local storage) into an array of real `Book` instances ...

```js
function Book(title, author, pages, read = false) {
  // just a container of book specific data.
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
}
Book.prototype.status = function() {
  // `status` preferably is implemented as prototype method.
  console.log(this.read);
}


const mybooks = [
  new Book('Hello', 'John', 123, true),
  new Book('Hey', 'Jane', 13, false),
  new Book('Hi', 'Mary', 12, true),
  new Book('Holo', 'Peter', 10, false),
  new Book('Banda', 'Banda', 03, true),
];
// const [book1, book2, book3, book4, book5] = mybooks;

mybooks.forEach(book => book.status());


// localStorage.setItem('mybooks', JSON.stringify(mybooks));
const storageValue = JSON.stringify(mybooks);

console.log('storageValue :', storageValue);


// const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mybooks'));
const storageData = JSON.parse(storageValue);

console.log('storageData ... raw book data :', storageData);

// there is no status method at neither raw book data item ...
console.log('storageData[0].status :', storageData[0].status);
console.log('storageData[4].status :', storageData[4].status);

// ... but one nevertheless can work with each raw data item ...
console.log('raw book data item `status` delegation call ...');

storageData.forEach(rawBookDataItem =>
  // explicit delegation via `call`.
  Book.prototype.status.call(rawBookDataItem)
);


// map/transform raw book data items each into a `Book` instance ...
const listOfBookInstances = storageData.map(data =>
  new Book(data.title, data.author, data.pages, data.read)
);
console.log('listOfBookInstances :', listOfBookInstances);

// call `status` method on each (new) book instance.
listOfBookInstances.forEach(book => book.status());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hey @Peter Seliger, thanks a lot for the detailed feedback, the use of the prototype is a smart move, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** how you store values...

```
localStorage.mybooks = JSON.stringify(mybooks);
```

Use this instead...

```
localStorage.setItem("mybooks", JSON.stringify(mybooks));
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

---

As a secondary point, using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` will not do anything with functions, just properties.

So instead you'll need to reassign the function on all the objects after you parse them.

To do this I would move the `status` function out of the `Book` function (I've called it `statusFnc` below)

Then when you've parsed the data, you can assign it back with your `forEach`

You can see a working example below, but note that I've had to comment out the `localStorage` lines, as that doesn't work in the snippet...

```js
// constructor function
function Book(title, author, pages, read = false) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.pages = pages;
  this.read = read;
  this.status = statusFnc;
}

// status function
let statusFnc = function() {
  console.log(this.read);
}

// array to store objects
let mybooks = [
  new Book('Hello', 'John', 123, true),
  new Book('Hey', 'Jane', 13, false),
  new Book('Hi', 'Mary', 12, true),
  new Book('Holo', 'Peter', 10, false),
  new Book('Banda', 'Banda', 03, true)
];

// store mybooks to the localStorage
//localStorage.mybooks = JSON.stringify(mybooks);
let json = JSON.stringify(mybooks);

// retrieve data from the localStorage
//let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('mybooks'));
let data = JSON.parse(json);

// reassign and call the status() method on each object
data.forEach(book => {
  book.status = statusFnc;
  book.status();
});
```

Comment: Hi @freefaller, thanks for the quick response. However, I have tried to store the info using the syntax that you suggested but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: Ah, ok, it's because `stringfy` will not convert a function... it will just deal with the properties. So the function would need to be re-created. Will update my answer shortly (please give me a short while to do so)

Comment: Sorry, have edited my answer, I shouldn't have been using `map`... when your `forEach` was more appropriate